# What is the latency for DNS / A records

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver

I recently registered a domain with MyDomain and set the name servers to:

- `ns1.example.com`
- `ns2.example.com`

I set the relevant A records to the IP address of the hosting account. It had a parking page just after I set it up, and now, something like 20 hours later, it still has a parking page.

Two questions:

1. Have I missed a step in setup for the FQDN to resolve to the IP?
2. What is the expected latency between "I entered the stuff above in MyDomain's DomainCentral" and "It now resolves to the desired IP"?

Comment: You can try to "help" DNS propagate quicker by _temporarily reducing the TTL (time to live) _before_ changing the DNS. But emphasise that this must be done sometime before you actually change the DNS (since this also needs to propagate). See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55411/domain-still-points-to-old-web-werver-after-deleting-domain-account/55413#55413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain when it comes to MyDomain specifically, but any normal DNS host will propagate within hours, 24 at most.

It *could* of course be that the DNS server **you** are using isn't updating for some reason. Try using Google's servers. Just type `nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8` to look it up using Google's DNS servers. Or, if you don't like Google, use OpenDNS or something.

Comment: Thank you; I went to set DNS to `8.8.8.8`, and MyDomain is saying, "
Records for `example.com` could not be updated. The nameserver you chose may not be a valid nameserver. Please verify with the provider and try again". I plan on discussing this with the ticket I opened.